# Css Sprite question, is there a better way?

Tags: css, sprite

I am a great lover of sprites, but. Got thinking, I do everything long hand, so was wondering if there was a shortcut.

Essentially, creating a sprite is easy. Making the sprite work is easy, but doing lots of sprites, gets laborious.

So was wondering what is the cleanest way of doing multiple sprites, that I can position anywhere on our web pages. I have seen multiple sprite sheets, similar to jquery ui icons, but we have our own icons. So was wondering if there was a cleaner method.

All up we will have approx 16 to 20 sprites in the set. Below is sample of html and css.

```
#logo-link
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(sprites/analytics.png);
    background-position:0 32px;
}
#logo-link:hover,#logo-link:active  { background-position:0 0; }

#logo-link2
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(sprites/addlisting.png);
    background-position:0 32px;
}
#logo-link2:hover,#logo-link2:active    { background-position:0 0; }
```

html

```
<a href="link1.html" id="logo-link"> </a>

<a href="link2.html" id="logo-link2"> </a>
```

Any thoughts, on refining our sprites. Or should we create a sprite sheet with all sprites on ?

Image sample:

[image]
[image]

Added basic sprite sheet on x axis

[image]

Example:

[image]

Ok Guys:

So far I have this in css:

```
.sprite
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(sprites/spritesheet.png);
}

.addlisting{background-position:0 32;}
.addlisting:hover{background-position:0 0;}
.addanalytics{background-position:64 32;}
.addanalytics:hover{background-position:64 0;}
.addprofile{background-position:32 32;}
.addprofile:hover{background-position:32 0;}
```

html I have:

```
<a href="link2.html" class="sprite addlisting"> </a>

<a href="link2.html" class="sprite addanalytics"> </a>

<a href="link2.html" class="sprite addprofile"> </a>
```

What I really dont get ( see the spritesheet.png I made above , is why profile is at co-ordinates 32,32 and why analytics is at co-ordinates 64,32

Perhaps I have my co-ords wrong lol

**This is driving me mad now, argghhh**

Added the actual sprite sheet now, but I am buggered if I can get so-ordinates to play with me lol
Image added:

![alt text][5]

Finally figured it out.

Comment: Something related, if you want to get the sprite x and y in ease, use tools like http://www.getspritexy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the selectors like so.

```
#logo-link,#logo-link2
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-position:0 32px;
}
#logo-link:hover,#logo-link:active,#logo-link2:hover,#logo-link2:active {background-position:0 0;}

#logo-link{background-image:url(sprites/analytics.png);}
#logo-link2{background-image:url(sprites/addlisting.png);}
```

Alternatively you could add a class called sprite

```
.sprite
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-position:0 32px;
}
.sprite:hover,.sprite:active {background-position:0 0;}

#logo-link{background-image:url(sprites/analytics.png);}
#logo-link2{background-image:url(sprites/addlisting.png);}
```

And the html

```
<a href="link1.html" id="logo-link" class="sprite"> </a>

<a href="link2.html" id="logo-link2" class="sprite"> </a>
```

**Edit**: Here is another alternative if you plan on using a sprite sheet.

```
.sprite
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(spritesheet.png);
}
.analytics{background-position:0 0;}
.analytics:hover{background-position:0 0;}
.addlisting{background-position:0 0;}
.addlisting:hover{background-position:0 0;}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="link2.html" class="sprite addlisting"> </a>
```

And a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gJkCZ/

Comment: Thats a cleaner version of what I have, untested. But doesnt reference a sprite sheet does it ? If so , how so ?

Comment: This references single images, not a sprite sheet.

Comment: Cheers Lime. Having a play, as most sites use the ul li method, which i dont want to use.

Comment: What do you mean by the "ul li method"

Comment: Sorry, ul and li method is what: http://www.narga.net/css-sprites-techniques-tutorials-and-tools/ use

Comment: I have updated question, with code. Something somewhere is wrong, I think I have my x axis and y axis knickers in a twist

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is.  This jsfiddle appears to be working fine unless I misunderstood your question. http://jsfiddle.net/gJkCZ/

Comment: Why is the analytics one at position x=64 ? and chosen your answer as best thanks

Comment: UPDATED *** Main Question, with the actual sprite sheet

Comment: I highly recommend that you install firefox and the firebug extension.  It will help so much with understanding html and css.  http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Nah finally figured it out, I was getting my axis and + and - all to cock, all fixed now. Cheers. Have updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Using a sprite sheet is beneficial to both the server and the end users, because the browser only needs to download one image instead of multiple images. Therefore, whe navigating to different pages, the browser does not need to download additional images since the master sprite sheet has already been received.

Also, in regards to your stylesheet, it may be easier to have a master link class that sets everything except the background-position property. This would decrease the size of the CSS and make it easier to modify in the future.

Comment: Yeah , it makes sense and I understand the less url requests the better. The issue is, creating a master sprite sheet. Searched on Google, didnt get very far. I struggle understanding the reference plot positions, for the sprites. Do I create one master sheet in gray and one in blue ? Then reference them separately to their co-ordinates, with hover effect. If so what plot position do i reference, bottom left of image, top right etc etc

Comment: A sprite sheet can be designed in any way. You can use any size spacing, including no spacing at all. The layout of the sheet is entirely up to you. I do recommend using only one sheet. What you can do, for example, is create one sheet with only blue images and converting it to grayscale. Then you can combine the sheets into one.

Comment: Ok, the fundamentals I understand. My images are 32px x 32px. So figured, I would create 4 x 4 grid in blue, with no padding between, as the images naturally do not go to borders. However, I dont get how I would refer in css terms, to row 3 column 1 sprite. If that makes sense, and which point on that grid is the reference point to produce the sprite.
Do I just go, x=128 y = 96 (px ) essentially ?

So background-position:128 96;

Comment: This is how the browser renders the background-position property: the coordinates you set for background-position are in the format "[x]px [y]px"; this becomes the origin, and the visible portion is defined by the size of the element.

Comment: @Evan , yep got that. I just dont get the way in which it interacts with the style sheet , and the corresponding html. I think I am looking at this too linearly ( is that a word )

I suppose, each class needs its own reference within css.
So for example: to display one particular sprite.
background-image:url(sprites/spritesheet.png);background-position:64 32px;
}

Comment: Yes, each button would use a different position location to display a different sprite. This site shows how Apple and YouTube use CSS sprites: http://www.narga.net/css-sprites-techniques-tutorials-and-tools/

Comment: Cheers Evan, I am slooooowly getting there. I updated main post with demo code ? Not sure if thats the basics ?

Comment: That's all there is to it. With the code you posted, the gray graph image would be displayed. I'm assuming that is what you want given the linked page is "analytics.HTML".

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks. I have updated original question, still having issues lol.

Comment: The top left image in your sprite sheet has coordinates 0,0. Therefore, the adjacent one has 32,0 and the analytics image has 64,0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in asp.net then there has been a framework released recently which is dedicated to handling this problem. Its call ASP.NET Sprite & Image Optimization Framework:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2010/08/06/asp-net-sprite-amp-image-optimization-framework-intro-in-webforms.aspx
- http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50869

The approach it takes is as follows:

- You create the images as normal individual images
- The framework takes all of your separate individual images, combines them into a sprite sheet and generates the css for it

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I've figured out. Basically because each image in the main menu (http://www.kintek.com.au) is a different width, I specify a width and background position on the #id.

Css

```
ul.menu li a{
    background: url(/images/menu/nav.png) no-repeat;
    height:77px;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
a#home{width:73px;background-position:0 -3px;}
a#home:hover, a#home.selected {background-position:0 -83px;}

a#services{width:90px;background-position:-231px -3px;}
a#services:hover, a#services.selected {background-position:-231px -83px;}
```

Markup

```
<li><a id="home"?> title="Kintek Web Design, Brisbane">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="services" class="selected">Services</a>
```

Comment: Yeah I dont want to use ul and li, as stated in the Question, we have the sprites doted all over the pages etc. So restricting using list methodology wont really work. Cheers